# file_get_contents to do a http request on the same domain

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, php-5.3, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use file_get_contents to retrieve the output a browser would receive from another file on the same domain.
I've moved to another server and now it always gets a timeout.
Below is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/sample.php');
?>
```

**sample.php**

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

Any ideas what might be the cause of this problem?

**EDIT**
Our server manager mentioned something about apache not responding to localhost, does that perhaps ring a bell?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you doing it over HTTP?  A filesystem operation is significantly less overhead than a HTTP request.

Comment: To your edit: yes, it does ring a bell. That's what I mentioned in the last sentence of my answer. That does mean you can't really do anything about it that's reliable and not horribly convoluted. Tell the server manager to make Apache respond to the localhost requests. Why would that have been disabled anyway?

Comment: @GrodonM, consider it a experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the URL is actually correct? Have you tried using `$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST']` instead? On the machine that runs PHP, what does the host from the generated URL resolve to? Has your web server (Apache?) been set up listen on the localhost interface?

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` variable is not always available on all architectures.

Comment: The URL is valid. when outputting it i can access it via the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fsockopen to do the same , along  with you can specify the timeout

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30/*timeout*/);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET /sample.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Check documentation for more details

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php